# Java Thread Cooperation with Three Threads Prints Extra Numbers

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety, java-threads, thread-synchronization

I am trying to print three AP sequences (in increments of 3) by three threads as follows:

- Thread-1 is printing the sequence `1, 4, 7, 10, ...`
- Thread-2 is printing the sequence `2, 5, 8, ...`
- Thread-3 is printing the sequence `3, 6, 9, ...`

A thread should wait while any other threads are taking their turns to print a number of their sequence. The threads should cooperate with each other to print the numbers sequentially from 1 to LIMIT (an integer; here LIMIT = 10).

### Expected Output

(For LIMIT = 10)

```
1 (printed by Thread-1)
2 (printed by Thread-2)
3 (printed by Thread-3)
4 (printed by Thread-1)
5 (printed by Thread-2)
6 (printed by Thread-3)
7 (printed by Thread-1)
8 (printed by Thread-2)
9 (printed by Thread-3)
10 (printed by Thread-1)
```

### Actual Output

(For LIMIT = 10)

```
1 (printed by Thread-1)
2 (printed by Thread-2)
3 (printed by Thread-3)
4 (printed by Thread-1)
5 (printed by Thread-2)
6 (printed by Thread-3)
7 (printed by Thread-1)
8 (printed by Thread-2)
9 (printed by Thread-3)
10 (printed by Thread-1)
11 (printed by Thread-2)
12 (printed by Thread-3)
```

### Code

```
class PrintingSequences {
    private static final int LIMIT = 10;
    int counter = 1;
    boolean isPrinting = false;

    // prints 1, 4, 7, 10, ...
    synchronized void printAPStartingFrom1() {
        while (counter <= LIMIT) {
            while (isPrinting || counter % 3 != 1) {
                try {
                    wait();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    System.out.println(e);
                    Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                }
            }
            isPrinting = true;
            System.out.println(counter++ + " (printed by " + Thread.currentThread().getName() + ")");
            isPrinting = false;
            notifyAll();
        }
    }

    // prints 2, 5, 8, 11, ...
    synchronized void printAPStartingFrom2() {
        while (counter <= LIMIT) {
            while (isPrinting || counter % 3 != 2) {
                try {
                    wait();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    System.out.println(e);
                    Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                }
            }
            isPrinting = true;
            System.out.println(counter++ + " (printed by " + Thread.currentThread().getName() + ")");
            isPrinting = false;
            notifyAll();
        }
    }

    // prints 3, 6, 9, 12, ...
    synchronized void printAPStartingFrom3() {
        while (counter <= LIMIT) {
            while (isPrinting || counter % 3 != 0) {
                try {
                    wait();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    System.out.println(e);
                    Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                }
            }
            isPrinting = true;
            System.out.println(counter++ + " (printed by " + Thread.currentThread().getName() + ")");
            isPrinting = false;
            notifyAll();
        }
    }
}

public class TripleThreadCommunication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        PrintingSequences naturalNumbers = new PrintingSequences();

        new Thread("Thread-1") {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                naturalNumbers.printAPStartingFrom1();
            }
        }.start();

        new Thread("Thread-2") {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                naturalNumbers.printAPStartingFrom2();
            }
        }.start();

        new Thread("Thread-3") {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                naturalNumbers.printAPStartingFrom3();
            }
        }.start();
    }
}
```

The program has three different synchronized methods: `printAPStartingFrom1()`, `printAPStartingFrom2()`, `printAPStartingFrom3()`, invoked by Thread-1, Thread-2, and Thread-3 respectively. The threads cooperate with each other using `wait()` and `notifyAll()` methods.

Why is the output consistently involving two additional numbers which are exceeding the given limit of 10, i.e., 11 and 12?

Comment: You omitted the crucial bit... the actual output showing which thread printed which number.

Comment: @JimGarrison I have edited the outputs to include the names of the threads

Comment: This seems very painful, and doesn't seem likely to teach you anything.

Comment: @NathanHughes I wanted to use this as a demonstration of inter-thread communication between three threads for the learners. But the unexpected output is baffling me.

Comment: This doesn't seem like a great way of demonstrating inter-thread communication. Maybe try using Actors?

Comment: @NathanHughes I had intended to use this as a demonstration of wait() and notifyAll() methods in a scenario involving three threads. I do understand threads can have unexpected behavior and this is probably not very useful. Just meant it as a proof of concept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a thread is woken up(`wait`->`runnable`), it needs to judge again whether the current `counter` is less than `LIMIT`, otherwise, it will continue to print until `while (counter <= LIMIT)` does not hold.(That's why `11` and `12` are printed too).

I would suggest that you determine in advance how many times each thread will loop(This will make the code simpler):

```
    // thread1
    // prints 1, 4, 7, 10, ...
    synchronized void printAPStartingFrom1() {
        int count = LIMIT % 3 == 0 ? LIMIT / 3 : LIMIT / 3 + 1;
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            while (counter % 3 != 1) {
                wait();
            }
            printAndAddCounter();
            notifyAll();
        }
    }
    // thread2
    // prints 2, 5, 8, 11, ...
    synchronized void printAPStartingFrom1() {
        int count = (LIMIT - 1) % 3 == 0 ? LIMIT / 3 : LIMIT / 3 + 1;
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            while (counter % 3 != 2) {
                wait();
            }
            printAndAddCounter();
            notifyAll();
        }
    }
    // thread3
    // prints 3, 6, 9, 12, ...
    synchronized void printAPStartingFrom1() {
        int count = LIMIT / 3;
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            while (counter % 3 != 0) {
                wait();
            }
            printAndAddCounter();
            notifyAll();
        }
    }
```